# Spring Data JPA: find by json property

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring Data JPA and one of the properties of my model is a `jsonb` column in PostgreSQL. This is how it's mapped:

```
@Type(type = "catalog.utils.model.JsonbType")
@Column(name = "marc", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private Marc marc;
```

This object is saved, retrieved and updated just fine. Then in my repository I made a method to retrieve by a certain `json` property. This query works fine in PostgreSQL:

```
public interface AuthorityRepository  extends JpaRepository<Authority, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Authority> {

    @Query(
            value = "SELECT * FROM my_table where marc -> 'controlNumber' = :controlNumber",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<Authority> findAuthoritiesByControlNumber(@Param("controlNumber") String controlNumber);
}
```

When I try to use this method of my repository I get this error: `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

In the console, I see the query executed just as I described and this error message, which I find confusing since the same query works fine when executed directly in PostgreSQL.

```
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

By these pieces of code is it possible to identify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like `jsonb` is(was) not supported by hibernate, but (obviously) we can adopt/customize: https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/ (resp. https://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate+jsonb)

Comment: @xerx593 you are right. That's what I'm using already.

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix. This is my repository :

```
public interface AuthorityRepository  extends JpaRepository<Authority, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Authority> {

    @Query(
            value = "SELECT * FROM my_tables where marc @> CAST(:jsonString as jsonb)",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<Authority> findAuthoritiesByJsonProperty(@Param("jsonString")  String jsonString);
}
```

And this is how I query it:

```
public List<Authority> getAuthoritiesByControlNumber(String controlNumber) {
    return this.repo.findAuthoritiesByJsonProperty("{\"controlNumber\": \""+ controlNumber +"\"}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me a similar query worked after replacing -> with ->>

So in your case it would be:

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT * FROM my_table where marc ->> 'controlNumber' = :controlNumber",
        nativeQuery = true
)
List<Authority> findAuthoritiesByControlNumber(@Param("controlNumber") String controlNumber);
}
```

This was my query:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable WHERE myjsonbcolomn ->> 'order_number' = :orderNumber")
  List<InvoiceDao> findByOrderNumber(@Param("orderNumber") String orderNumber);
```